# Callback function with parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, callback, pagemethods

I'm using AJAX Page Methods, but I can't seem to be able to pass the needed parameters:

```
  function getFavStatus() {
    //favs is a list of DOM <imgs> that I want to modify their img.src attribute
    for (i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
      PageMethods.isFavorite(favs[i].alt,setFavImg(favs[i]));
    }
  }

  function setFavImg(fav, response) {
    fav.src = response;
  }
```

The problem that I can't figure out is how to use the "response" from PageMethods, AND pass the DOM object to the callback function.

I've also tried doing something like this:

```
 function getFavStatus() {
    for (i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
      PageMethods.isFavorite(favs[i].alt, function (response) {
                favs[i].src = response;});   
      );
    }
  }
```

In this case, the response works properly, but `i` is always `> favs.length`, because it has already iterated through the loop...

**Edit**: My PageMethods.isFavorite signature is:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string isFavorite ( string p_id )
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the syntax of `PageMethods.isFavourite`? Can you paste that method here?

Comment: Not very familiar with Page Methods, but what if you change `favs[i].src = response;` to be `this.src = response;` instead?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - this refers to the Window, not the favs[i]

Comment: Also not too familiar with how PageMethods works, but if it worked as you want it to (e.g. making one async call for each iteration of the loop) this would be really inefficient. Why don't you instead build a delimited list of p_ids in javascript and change isFavorite to accept a list and return a list? That way you only call it once, avoiding the problem and also having only a single async call. It may be that something in the design of PageMethods tries to reduce this loop to a single async call which is itself the source of your problem.

Comment: @jamietre - That isn't a bad idea, but now I'm curious at why this is necessary if I want to pass response to setFavImg: `PageMethods.isFavorite(favs, function (response) { setFavImg(response) });`, why can't I just call `PageMethods.isFavorite(favs,setFavImg(response));`?

Comment: @Brett - @Brian's answer confirms my suspicion about how PageMethods works. Not sure what you mean in your last comment, but setFavImg has two parameters, maybe that is just brevity? Is the question why you can't call a setFavImg from the anonymous function (you should be able to), or why it doesn't work in the loop, I think @Brian answered the latter.

Comment: OK saw your edit. Try `PageMethods.isFavorite(favs,setFavImg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
PageMethods.isFavorite(favs[i].alt, 
  function (response, ctx) {
       /* success callback */
       ctx.src = response;
  },
  function(response) { /* failed callback */ },
  favs[i] /* context */);
```

The context is passed to the callbacks, so you can pass in the reference to the image to the callbacks, and set it in the callback there.

The original issue is that the page methods is asynchronous, so the callback isn't firing until after the loop completes.  Hence the last item being affected.

HTH.

Comment: Yeah, I got as far as the callback not firing until after the loop completes, but I don't understand how I would be setting ctx in this example?

Comment: @Brett: The idea is that the last parameter you pass to `isFavorite` (here `favs[i]`) gets passed back to you as the second parameter (`ctx`) in the callback.

Comment: @psmears - I had missed the last parameter in that (`favs[i]`), but now it makes perfect sense, and does work! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea that will save lots of trouble although it's not very elegant.

Have the page method return **two** strings (i.e. array with two string items) - the first string will be the ID of image element and the second will be the desired source.

Then the callback function will become:

```
function (response) {
    document.getElementById(response[0]).src = response[1];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that work, I had previously done something like that, but at the moment I'm trying to more or less learn how this works. Hence why I'm trying to do it this way... But I do appreciate the answer! Thanks

Comment: @Brett the "problem" is with the client side implementation of the ASP.NET page methods - looks like they're not storing the context, if they were `this` would have worked same way it works in client side events.

Answer (score 1):

Brian's answer is probably the cleanest way to do this, but an alternative (if the `ctx` parameter weren't supported) that solves the issue of `i` always being at the end of the loop is to use a closure to preserve the value of `i`:

```
function createCallback(i) {
    return function (response) {
        favs[i].src = response;
    }
}

function getFavStatus() {
    for (i = 0; i < favs.length; i++) {
      PageMethods.isFavorite(favs[i].alt, createCallback(i));   
    }
  }
```

Comment: so what you did for this was forced it to pass by value, rather than passing by reference (when i > favs.length)?

Comment: @Brett: Effectively, yes... though actually what is happening is that there's still a reference being passed around, but it's a reference to the local `i` in `CreateCallback`, and since that function is called multiple times, a different `i` is created each time. So the current value at the time of each call gets preserved.